# JBoss AS 5.x EOL?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss5.x

I can't find any official date on the JBoss web site when JBoss AS 5.x will be end-of-life. Can anyone give me a hint where to look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found it: 
https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/jboss_notes/